# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, windows

***The shell script snippet is given below***

```
if [[ $OS == Linux ]] ; then

    LINUX_FC=gfortran
#
#   set 32 or 64 Bits executable
#
    ARCH=`uname -m`
    echo "PROCESSOR IS: $ARCH"
    if [ [ $ARCH == x86_64 ] ]  ; then
        BITS=SIXTYFOUR;
    else
        BITS=THIRTYTWO;
    fi

elif [[ $OS == Darwin ]] ; then

        DARWIN_FC=gfortran;

else
    BITS=THIRTYTWO;
fi;
```

***Error is***

```
OPERATING SYSTEM IS: Linux
: command not found
jobcomp1: line 34: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
'obcomp1: line 34: `elif [ [ $OS == Darwin ] ] ; then
```

Comment: [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) is your friend.

Comment: When you edit shell scripts under Windows, make sure to use Unix line endings.

Answer (score 4):

The shell really does not like those blanks between the brackets:

```
if [ [ $ARCH == x86_64 ] ]  ; then
```

It expects something like

```
if [[ $ARCH == x86_64 ]]  ; then
```

or (better)

```
if [ $ARCH = x86_64 ]  ; then
```

(there is no point in making a script bash-specific, so the `==` becomes `=` as well).

Comment: You should write: `if [ "$ARCH" = x86_64 ]  ; then`. Quote your expansions. Inside a `[[ … ]]` quoting is not a problem.

Comment: sure: if you expect to run the script on a system without `uname`.  But that's a different question than asked.

Comment: Yes, that's another error, but not the one causing the messages in the question because the shell doesn't even see that command due to the other error which is the missing `then` (there's a `then$'\r'`).